# Add more new items to listbox?

Tags: tkinter, listbox

using tkinter/python im trying to add a item when button click to a listbox (tkinter) but only one is diplayed afther new clicks.

my code for create listbox is:

```
def add_to_list(data):
    list = Listbox(frame1, width=40, height=4)
    list.insert(END,data)
    list.place(x=5, y=90)

Btn_Add_l = Button(frame1, text="Add", padx=8, pady=4, command=lambda: add_to_list("hello new item"))
```

More click on button dont add new item ,what can be the error?

Comment: Please show us a complete [mcve]. You're asking us to diagnose a function which you haven't included in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Every time the button is pressed you keep creating new listbox widgets. You have to create 1 listbox and just insert data when the button is pressed like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def add_to_list(data):
    listbox_widget.insert("end", data)

root = tk.Tk()
listbox_widget = tk.Listbox(root, width=40, height=4)
listbox_widget.pack()

command = lambda: add_to_list("hello new item")
button = tk.Button(root, text="Add", padx=8, pady=4, command=command)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```